# How to move particles along a plane without moving the plane?

Tags: animation, particles

I'm attempting to make an animation which is going down a road in first person view. I'd like to do this without having to make just a very long plane of grass on the sides of the road. My question is, is it possible to make the grass particles move along the plane instead? As in they don't stay in the same position the entire time (though the plane will), and are also moving past the camera?

Comment: With Hair particles, I don't think you can. But with Emitter particles, you can give them a starting speed (in Velocity, set Normal to 0.0 then choose the axis you want them to move). You'll probably want to disable gravity (in Field Weight, set Gravity to 0.0). The downside is, you'll loose some benefits of Hair rendering (like Stands)